# Compare two arrays by content in Javascript in BDD style

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, bdd, mocha.js

I would like to compare two different arrays by content using mocha and should.

Right now I use [underscore.difference](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) to do so:

**test.js**

```
var should  = require('should')
var _       = require('underscore')

_.difference(['one', 'two'], [ 'two']).should.eql([])
```

Execution of **mocha test.js** produces pretty readable result:

> AssertionError: expected [ 'one' ] to equal []

Is there a better way to compare two arrays and have exact information what is different?

Comment: What do you mean by better way? What's wrong with the current approach?

Comment: it works, but current logic is inverted - get the difference between two arrays and compare to the empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is fine. The two corrections are that instead of underscore, I would switch to lodash, which is API compatible but much faster.

But in your example, I would skip lodash/underscore, and just do:

```
(['one', 'two']).should.eql(['two', 'three'])
```

If you want the error message to show you what is different (and it's not so obvious), you should stick to lodash.